# How to sum numeric values in a character vector?

Tags: r, string, sum

I have a data frame with rows containing several numbers in each row. The data type of each column in the data frame is `factor`.

My data frame looks like

```
> df
           C1
1 1, 14, 1, 4
2           2
3          NA
4     3, 7, 5
```

Now I want to sum up the values of each element in `df`. Such that I get

```
  Sum
1  20
2   2
3  NA
4  15
```

I tried `strsplit(as.character(df$C1),split=",")`. However I have no idea how to build get the sum...

```
df <- data.frame(C1= c("1, 14, 1, 4", "2", NA, "3, 7, 5"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your code:

```
 sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$C1), split=","),
                       function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))
 #[1] 20  2 NA 15
```

Or

```
library(splitstackshape)
Sum1 <- rowSums(cSplit(df, 'C1', sep=','), na.rm=TRUE)
#Assuming that there is only one column
Sum1[!Sum1] <- NA
Sum1
#[1] 20  2 NA 15
```

Or may be this also

```
unname(sapply(gsub(",", "+", df$C1),
            function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))
# [1] 20  2 NA 15
```

Answer (score 4):

Converting your data to a data.frame and using `rowSums`:

```
rowSums(read.table(text=as.character(df$C1),sep=',',fill=TRUE),na.rm=TRUE)

[1] 20  2  0 15
```

Answer (score 1):

A mostly for fun approach using `eval` `parse`:

```
unlist(lapply(paste0("c(", as.character(df$C1), ")"), function(x) sum(eval(parse(text=x)))))
## [1] 20  2 NA 15
```